# How to send the emoji parallel with live chat using core php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, node.js, jquery-ui

we are using this script for integrate **emoji** but that is not working in other system. Current sytem can view the emojis but not able to view with other  system.

```
<script>
     // ask user for name with popup prompt    
      var name = prompt("Enter your chat name:", "Guest");

      // default name is 'Guest'
      if (!name || name === ' ') {
     name = "Guest";  
 }
    // strip tags
    name = name.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
    // display name on page
    $("#name-area").html("You are: <span>" + name + "</span>");
    // kick off chat
    var chat =  new Chat();
    $(function() {
       chat.getState(); 
         // watch textarea for key presses
         $("#sendie").keydown(function(event) {  
           var key = event.which;  
             //all keys including return.  
             if (key >= 33) {
               var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");  
               var length = this.value.length;  

                 // don't allow new content if length is maxed out
                 if (length >= maxLength) {  
                   event.preventDefault();  
               }  
           }  
       });
         // watch textarea for release of key press
         $('#sendie').keyup(function(e) {   
          if (e.keyCode == 13) { 
            e.preventDefault();
            var text = $(this).val();
            var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");  
            var length = text.length; 
            var str = '';
            str = $.trim($("#sendie").val());
                // send 
                if (length <= maxLength + 1) { 
                    $(this).val("");

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "parsetext.php",
                        data: {str: addslashes(str)},
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(html) {

                           chat.send(text, name);  
                            $("#chat-area").append(name + html);

                        },
                        error: function(html) {
                                    //alert("Failed");
                                }
                            });


                } else {

                    $(this).val(text.substring(0, maxLength));

                }   
            }
        });
     });
function addslashes(str) {
    return (str + '').replace(/[\\"']/g, '\\$&').replace(/\u0000/g,  '\\0');}
</script>
<body onload="setInterval('chat.update()', 1000)">

<div id="page-wrap">

    <h2>jQuery/PHP Chat</h2>

    <p id="name-area"></p>

    <div id="chat-wrap"><div id="chat-area"></div></div>

    <form id="send-message-area">
        <p>Your message: </p>
        <textarea id="sendie" maxlength = '100' ></textarea>
    </form>

</div>
</body>
```

When we have enter the any text that is viewed in another system but the **emoji** is not view with them.

```
<?php
$function = $_POST['function'];

$log = array();

switch($function) {

     case('getState'):
         if(file_exists('chat.txt')){
           $lines = file('chat.txt');
         }
         $log['state'] = count($lines); 
         break; 

     case('update'):
        $state = $_POST['state'];
        if(file_exists('chat.txt')){
           $lines = file('chat.txt');
         }
         $count =  count($lines);
         if($state == $count){
             $log['state'] = $state;
             $log['text'] = false;

             }
             else{
                 $text= array();
                 $log['state'] = $state + count($lines) - $state;
                 foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line)
                   {
                       if($line_num >= $state){
                     $text[] =  $line = str_replace("\n", "", $line);
                       }

                    }
                 $log['text'] = $text; 
             }

         break;

     case('send'):
      $nickname = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['nickname']));
         $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
          $message = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['message']));
     if(($message) != "\n"){

         if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $message, $url)) {
            $message = preg_replace($reg_exUrl, '<a href="'.$url[0].'" target="_blank">'.$url[0].'</a>', $message);
            } 


         fwrite(fopen('chat.txt', 'a'), "<span>". $nickname . "</span>" . $message = str_replace("\n", " ", $message) . "\n"); 
     }
         break;

}

echo json_encode($log);
?>
```

i have a added the process.php file.

```
 <?php
  function parseString($string ) {
   $my_smilies = array(
    ':aln' => '<img src="images/alien1.png" alt="" />',
    ':thk' => '<img src="images/annoyed.png" alt="" />',
    ':ang' => '<img src="images/angel.png" alt="" />',
    ':slp<' => '<img src="images/zzz.png" alt="" />',
    ':blnk' => '<img src="images/blanco.png" alt="" />',
    ':zip' => '<img src="images/zip_it.png" alt="" />',
    ':bor' => '<img src="images/boring.png" alt="" />',
    ':brb' => '<img src="images/brb.png" alt="" />',
    ':bsy' => '<img src="images/busy.png" alt="" />',
    ':cell' => '<img src="images/cellphone.png" alt="" />',
    ':tp' => '<img src="images/clock.png" alt="" />',
    ':cool' => '<img src="images/cool.png" alt="" />',
    ':czy' => '<img src="images/crazy.png" alt="" />',
    ':cry' => '<img src="images/cry.png" alt="" />',
    ':dvl' => '<img src="images/devil.png" alt="" />',
    ':blush' => '<img src="images/blush.png" alt="" />',
    ':stop' => '<img src="images/dnd.png" alt="" />',
    ':flwr' => '<img src="images/flower.png" alt="" />',
    ':heart' => '<img src="images/heart.png" alt="" />',
    ':geek' => '<img src="images/geek.png" alt="" />',
    ':gift' => '<img src="images/gift.png" alt="" />',
    ':ill' => '<img src="images/ill.png" alt="" />',
    ':love' => '<img src="images/in_love.png" alt="" />',
    ':file' => '<img src="images/text_file.png" alt="" />',
    ':kiss' => '<img src="images/kissy.png" alt="" />',
    ':laugh' => '<img src="images/laugh.png" alt="" />',
    ':mail' => '<img src="images/mail.png" alt="" />',
    ':music' => '<img src="images/music2.png" alt="" />',
    ':whst' => '<img src="images/not_guilty.png" alt="" />',
    ':please' => '<img src="images/please.png" alt="" />',
    ':info' => '<img src="images/info.png" alt="" />',
    ':sad' => '<img src="images/sad.png" alt="" />',
    ':silly' => '<img src="images/silly.png" alt="" />',
    ':lol' => '<img src="images/oh.png" alt="" />',
    ':slps' => '<img src="images/speechless.png" alt="" />',
    ':srpd' => '<img src="images/surprised.png" alt="" />',
    ':tease' => '<img src="images/tease.png" alt="" />',
    ':wink' => '<img src="images/wink.png" alt="" />',
    ':grin' => '<img src="images/xd.png" alt="" />'
   );

   return str_replace( array_keys($my_smilies), array_values($my_smilies),         $string);
}

$str = stripslashes( $_POST["str"]);
echo '<strong>me: </strong> '.parseString($str).'<br>';
?>
```

i have a added the parsetext.php file.

Comment: It is not clear from this code what is not working.

Comment: I have added the second file in which the process code is mention for chat. emojis is not view in another browser.

Comment: So, it sounds like when content arrives (a chat message is received), and it contains an emoji, the text is not converted into the emoji. When the message is typed up, the emoji appears, is this correct?

Comment: chat message is working in parallel mode, with send and receive but when i add the emoji that is unable to view with the receiver side. it can only visible with the sender browser not with the receiver browser.

Comment: When `parsetext.php` returns data in the ajax call, can you provide an example of the html that is returned?

Comment: Also, can you show an example of what is sent to the receiver?

Comment: if we have text the meaasge with :aln this emoji images is only view with sender side with the text and emoji. but on receiver side only text is view not the emoji.